# Templates and markup

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates, markup

I use the Google App Engine and I have faced with the next problem. I need to store in the Datastorage text like "<p>My text</p>". When I used the templates of Django 0,96 everything was in order. The text was shown with expected markup. But I was change the templates to templates of Django 1.2, and my markup has been changed to HTML entities. How to solve this problem?

P.S. I don't use the Django helper or any other third-party libraries.

---

If a filter mode is default mode for templates so using  the "safe" or "autoescape on" looks like a hack.  I'm trying to understand how Django's authors imagined themselves templates using. I do not think that journalists in addition to the materials publication also create templates for each of its articles. I.e. must be some means of allowing format text,  tinyMCE, or Markdown for example. But when markup stored in DB then templates show it as html entities.

Of course, it is possible to use filters "safe" or "autoescape on". But I don't understand for what sanitize in templates when it will disable in most cases.

May be I haven't right? Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe), or the `autoescape off` template tag. Make sure you understand what XSS is first; user-input content should not be considered safe.

Re comments:

`{{ body|safe }}` is a shorter equivalent to the autoescape block. I've no idea why that didn't work, unless T. Abilo is right and the datastore has it html-quoted already.

TinyMCE is hard to guard against XSS, since it sends you presentational html back. Markdown editors (like MarkItUp) are easier since you can render the markdown safely on the server side. As it is you need a filter that strips everything but a presentational html whitelist: `{{ body|presentationalonly }}`. [This one](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2444/) could do the job. [Bleach](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach) is available for stricter whitelists.

Comment: I know about *autosave off* and use it, but it nothing changes. My code:

    {% extends "index.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        <h2>{{ section_title }}</h2>
        {% autoescape off %}
        <p>{{ body }}</p>
        {% endautoescape %}
        <p>{{ publication }}</p>
    {% endblock %}

May be I didn't configure enough  GAE and Django? I only was add webapp_django_version = '1.2' into the empty appengine_config.py.

Comment: I know also about XSS. But I don't  understand enough how to currently combine django1.2 templates and text formatted with, for example, TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem so maybe you could check the following:

- is the markup showing as `"&lt;p&gt;&lt;"` etc. in your datastore?
- if so, you can add this in your template to the string `.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">")` while still using autoescape or something similar
- if it works you can also change it directly in your handler, like described here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml